# Circuit protection incorporating a Transient Voltage Supressor and Polyfuse

Tags: circuit-protection, tvs, polyfuse

I want to protect some microprocessor equipment ( 5.0v, max 700mA ) which is powered by usb cell phone type chargers from damage due to such things as polarity reversal, over-voltage, power surges etc. I don't want a voltage drop (such as from a series diode) and it should sustain, without damage, a prolonged fault condition.

Is it simply enough to have a polyfuse in series with power input and afterwards a unidirectional transient voltage supressor (with 5.0v standoff voltage) reversed across power input ?

Eg

1PMT5.0AT1G 5.0v unidirectional TVS diode
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/1PMT5.0AT3-D-32851.pdf

LITTELFUSE  60R050XPR Polyfuse 1A tripping current.
http://uk.farnell.com/littelfuse/60r050xpr/resettable-fuse-60vdc-40a-radial/dp/2383313

Follow up question: Under what circumstances would a bi-directional TVS be used in this scenario ?

Comment: TVS can only sustain the harsh voltage for short time. Polyfuse takes considerable amount of time before jumping into action. How fast should the protection should act?

Comment: The combination of a polyfuse and a high power TVS can work. As Umar noted, the TVS must be capable of dissipating considerable power for a robust design. BUT, a TVS is not a precision voltage limiter. An incoming over-voltage may still expose VBUS to 7V or more before the polyfuse trips. If you need precision voltage protection, you may need a more precise voltage reference and a comparator based switch.

Comment: USB ports are usually protected with Polyfuse at source and Schottky power diode for reverse voltage protection. Anything better requires an IC with dual MOSFETs, comparator and current sensing.

Comment: There are also USB protection IC's available that simplify the design. Personally, I have never seen a Schottky on a USB device. My experience is with handheld, battery powered devices. We used USB protection IC's. Nowadays a lot of LDO's and USB USB chargers and are only rated to 6 or 7 V absolute maximum, so it is basically impossible to protect them without some kind of active switching. I have not used reverse polarity protection on USB devices because the connector is polarized.

Comment: Only for large OEM's https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/protection-control/protection-ics/MAX16969.html/NDARequestUSBProtectionProduct/?part_numbers=MAX16969&title=500mA%26%238211%3B3A+Automotive+Hi-Speed+USB+Protector+with+Apple+iPod+Fast-Charge+Detection+and+USB+Host-Charger+Port+Detection&partnumber=MAX16969

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, what is "only for large OEM's?"

Comment: Meaning they don't sell to hobbiests. Not stocked anywhere and you have to make a special request for the datasheet.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I hate maxim. But OP can look at NCP362 (onsemi) or TPD1S514x (TI). Or many others. "USB VBUS over voltage protection."

Comment: Many thanks for the contributions.
The devices I want to protect have an Atmega328p processor as the most sensitive element, and the data sheet specifies a  "Maximum Operating Voltage" of 6.0v. For convenience, I simply use USB chargers as their power source. The biggest risks I see are from cheap, faulty chargers (wrongly wired, failed/missing regulator etc. or surges in the electricity distribution network. I hadn't considered the response time of the polyfuse which appears to be in the order of 4 seconds with 2.5 Amps (trip current 1A) and will have to factor that in.

Comment: The NCP362, TPD1S514x and Maxim equivalent and similar look good but beyond my "TTH" soldering skills. Duplicating the same functionality with discrete components might be overkill in my application.

Comment: Comparator, voltage reference and PMOS. Use an RC to slow the rise time so that the circuit can react fast enough. It is doable. Could also use a crowbar.